# open URL link in center screen

Tags: javascript, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I develop an SSRS report with link URL that open a system screen in new window.

My problem is that the new window opens in the top left corner of the screen.

My current expression is:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('myURL.aspx?TaskID=" & Fields!TaskID.Value &    
"','_blank','width=1150,height=460'))"
```

Also Tried (nothing happend):

```
="javascript:void(window.open('myURL.aspx?TaskID=" & Fields!TaskID.Value &    
"','_blank','width=1150,height=460,left=100,top=100'))"
```

Also this one (still nothing happened):

```
="javascript:void(window.open('myURL.aspx?TaskID=" & Fields!TaskID.Value &    
"','_blank','width=1150,height=460','left=screen.width/2,top=screen.height/2'))"
```

Any suggestions how to open the new window in center of the screen ?

Comment: What browser and version?

Comment: This report is going to be a generic report (that going to be installed on customers' sites), so it can't be related to specific browsers

Comment: Where do you want the new window to be positioned?

Comment: In center of screen (as my title says :) )

Comment: Ah was looking for it in the question, sorry

Comment: I'm very certain your answer will be in the java script not related to ssrs and as JavaScript is number 1 on this site I've re-tagged your question. Nice question!

Comment: I let myself re-re-tag your tag (you mistakenly tagged `java` instead of `java-script` :)

Comment: Thanks, as you can see I'm neither proficient at java, javascript or **reading** ;)

Comment: Does `" + screen.width + "` and `" + screen.height + "` work in place of the `screen.width` and `screen.height`? as they are vb methods also.

Comment: Nope, I tried them but with no result :/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to get calculations with `screen.width` or `screen.height` working in Reporting Services, so centering a new window based on user's resolution seems to be out of reach for now.

Absolute values for `top` and `left` will work though. Check your syntax in the second attempt with absolute `left` and `top` values. Not sure if this is typo in the question or code. It should be:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('myURL.aspx?TaskID=" & Fields!TaskID.Value &    
"','_blank','width=1150,height=460,left=100,top=100'))"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jQuery, you can use [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) to determine window width and height. There may be some limitations, for which you can search in Google to find solutions. This worked for me in similar situation.

Comment: work for you over SSRS Report ? If so can you please provide the URL link that you used ?